# Any suggestions for combining scans of different frequencies?

Tags: ros, gazebo, lidar, scan, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm combining two scans, one extracted from a depth camera, and the other from a 2D LIDAR. But I'm getting some jitter from the depth camera's scan's contribution. I suppose it's to be expected when combining a 30Hz depth scan with a 40Hz LIDAR, but I was wondering if there was anything that could be done better. A qualitative example of the jitter artifact in RVIZ; red/LIDAR, green/depth-camera, yellow/combined. Note how combined lagges with the camera, and the LIDAR remains quite static.
[image: image description]

The example you see here is a turtlebot simulation from gazebo, with a asus pointing forward, and a gpu_lidar pointing backwards, using this small PR of ira_laser_tools: [#7](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools/pull/7). I made an issue [#8](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools/issues/8) of this, but thought It could be general enough for a good old approach question here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227094/any-suggestions-for-combining-scans-of-different-frequencies?/) by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1094 on 2016-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't trivial and especially with real sensors there will be additional problems due to noise (and different noise characteristic). That being said, I imagine using odometry (or z gyro/angular velocity data directly) during the merging process to rotate data appropriately is something that might help. For this to work correctly, the timestamps of the involved data have to be somewhat accurate, however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2016-02-19**:
Yep, I guess combining the scans with respect to the odom frame, then going back to the destination_frame  might improve this. Perhaps an amendment around [here](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools/blob/master/src/laserscan_multi_merger.cpp#L151)?